# Vbscript - Creating a script that mirrors several sets of folders

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, robocopy, active-directory-group

Ok, this is my problem.
I'm doing a logonscript that basically copies Microsoft Word templates from a serverpath on to a local path of each computer. This is done using a check for group membership.

```
If MemberOf(ObjGroupDict, "g_group1") Then
    oShell.Run "%comspec% /c %LOGONSERVER%\SYSVOL\mydomain.com\scripts\ROBOCOPY \\server\Templates\Group1\OFFICE2003\ " & TemplateFolder & "\" & " * /E /XO", 0, True
End If
```

Previously I used the /MIR switch of robocopy, which is exellent. 
But, if a user is member of more than one group, the /MIR switch removes the content from the first group, since it's mirroring the content from the second group. Meaning, I can't have both contents.

This is "solved" by not using the /MIR switch and just let the content get copied anyway. 
BUT the whole idea of having the templates on a server is so that I can control the content the users receive through the script. So if I delete a file or folder from the server path, this doesn't replicate on the local computer. Since I don't use the /MIR switch anymore. Comprende?

So, what do I do?
I did a small script that basically checks the folders and files and then removes them accordingly, but this actually ended up being the same functionality as the /MIR switch anyway. How do I solve this problem?

Edit: I've found that what I actually need is a routine that scans my local template folder for files and folders and checks if the same structure exists in any of the source template folders.

The server template folders are set up like this:

```
\\fileserver\templates\group1\
\\fileserver\templates\group2\
\\fileserver\templates\group3\
\\fileserver\templates\group4\
\\fileserver\templates\group5\
\\fileserver\templates\group6\
```

And the script that does the copying is structures like this (pseudo):

```
If User is MemberOf (group1) Then
   RoboCopy.exe \\fileserver\templates\group1\ c:\templates\workgroup *.* /E /XO
End if

If User is MemberOf (group2) Then
   RoboCopy.exe \\fileserver\templates\group2\ c:\templates\workgroup *.* /E /XO
End if

If User is MemberOf (group3) Then
   RoboCopy.exe \\fileserver\templates\group3\ c:\templates\workgroup *.* /E /XO
End if
```

Etc etc
With the /E switch, I make sure it copies subfolders as well. And the /XO switch only copies files and folders that are newer than those in my local path.
But it doesn't consider if the local path contains files or folders that doesn't exist on the server template path.

So after the copying is done, I would like to check if any of the files or folders on my c:\templates\workgroup actually exists in either of the sources. And if they don't, delete them from my local path. Something that could be combined in these memberchecks perhaps?

Comment: How do you expect this to work?  Unless you set up special template paths for users of multiple groups, in which case you would need a path for every combination of groups.  Each group will always overwrite the previous group, you may need a more complex solution.

Comment: What if you completely wipe out the users template directory, and then just copy each groups templates to there location?  This may take a lot more time since your doing a full copy each time, but at least you would always have the correct files.

Comment: Hi, the latter one is the method I actually use today that needs to be renewed :) I would need a more complex solution. And that's basically what I'm after now.

Answer (score 2):

**Using a lookup table**

I'd suggest an approach that puts all templates into one common file server directory and use a lookup table to assign templates to groups.

The benefit would be that your templates would be guaranteed to be in sync; i.e. you don't have to worry that a template for group A, B, and C is really the same in all group specific folders on your file server.

Another bonus is a maintainable configuration table which allows you to assign templates to groups without the need to make changes to your logon script.

The lookup table config file would look something like

```
group1;\templateA.dot;\templateA.dot
group2;\B\templateB.dot;\B\templateB.dot
group3;\B\C\templateC.dot;\templateC.dot
```

with column 1 listing your AD group names; column 2 the source path and column 3 the target path.
This would also allow for flattening your template folder on the client side.

In any case you can avoid having to maintain multiple copies of all your templates on your file server and adding more groups or templates doesn't require to touch your logon script but just the config file.

In your logon script you can iterate over all lines and copy the ones with matching groups

**Logon script code**

```
open lookup table config file

For Each line In lookup table
    If MemberOf(ObjGroupDict, groupname_column_value) Then
        execute Robocopy templatename_column_value local_target
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yeah, none of these are really what I'm looking for. I'm currently using Robocopy and I'll continue to do that. And Word cannot point it's template area to the server path, since all templates needs to work offline as well.

Comment: @Kenny Using a lookup table doesn't rule out to continue using Robocopy. It merely moves logic of which tempates to copy for which group from your script to a configuration file and allows to keep all templates together.

Comment: I'm gonna check out your solution today and find which one of these answers are best suited for me. Thumbs up for this one though :)

Comment: @Kenny: I didn't have the time to come up with a full script sample but I'd flesh out the details if you like the solution in general.

Answer (score 1):

**Removing old files on the client**

Here's a script that removes files in the template directory the user's machine not present in one of the file groups copied. For clarity, the code is at the end of this answer. Here's how to use the script in your current solution that doesn't use `/MIR`.

In the code for each group copied, add one additional method call to 'ListFiles' - this tracks the files copied from the server:

```
If User is MemberOf (group3) Then
   RoboCopy.exe \\fileserver\templates\group3\ c:\templates\workgroup *.* /E /XO
   ListFiles("\\fileserver\templates\group3\", userTemplates)
End if
```

Do this for each group copied. (It is ok if the same template appears in more than one group.)

After all groups have been copied, you add this code block:

```
   ListFiles "c:\templates\workgroup", toDelete
   removeAllFrom toDelete, userTemplates
```

This lists all files in the user's local templates folder to `toDelete`. All the files just copied are then removed from that set, leaving just the files that were not copied from the server. We can then print the files to delete, and then actually delete them.

```
   echoDictionary "deleting old user templates", toDelete
   ' deleteFiles c:\templates\workgroup", toDelete
```

The call to deleteFiles commented out - probably wise to do a trial run first! The first argument to deleteFiles is the user's template directory - it should not have a trailing slash.

With these changes in place, any files in the templates folder on the users machine that were not copied from the server will be deleted, providing effectively multi-directory synchronization.

Now comes the script. The first block can be pasted to the top of your file, and the remainder at the bottom, to help avoid clutter.

```
// script to remove files not present on one of the group folders on the fileserver

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set userTemplates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
userTemplates.CompareMode = 1
Set toDelete = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
toDelete.CompareMode = 1

-- under here are just procedures so they can go at 
-- the bottom of your script if desired

Sub deleteFiles(basedir, dictionary)
   for each key in dictionary.Keys
      fs.DeleteFile(basedir+"\"+key)             
   next
End Sub

Sub echoDictionary(msg, dictionary)
    for each key in dictionary.Keys
       Wscript.Echo msg & ": " & key
    next
End Sub


Sub removeAllFrom(target, toRemove)
   for each key in toRemove.Keys
      if target.Exists(key) then
         target.remove key
      end if
   next
End Sub

Sub ListFiles(folderName, dictionary)
    Set folder = fs.GetFolder(folderName)
    ListSubFolders folder, "", dictionary
End Sub

Sub ListSubFolders(folder, prefix, dictionary)
    Set files = folder.Files
    For Each file in files
         qualifiedName = prefix & file.Name
         dictionary.add qualifiedName, file
    Next

    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        qualifiedName = prefix+Subfolder.Name & "\"
        ListSubFolders Subfolder, qualifiedName, dictionary
        dictionary.add qualifiedName, Subfolder 
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Kenny - did you get chance to try this?

Comment: No, I didn't, but I'd like to set this to be the answer. But the check icon is gonorrhea.

Comment: Unfortunately, that happens when you don't select an answer before the 7-days bounty period is up. (Automatic selection will only choose the highest answer with score 2 or more.)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-an-answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty. I'm not sure what can be done about this. This the 3rd time this has happened to me in the month I've been a user - I hope they can sort out this bad behaviour with bounty questions.